# R integrate : evaluation of function gave a result of wrong type

Tags: r

I am having this annoying error again in R that I thought I understood well and I could avoid it for enough time. But now it's starting to haunt me again.

```
inner.f.y <- function(y)
{
    cat("length(y)   ", length(y), "\n")

    t<-2*y*exp((exp(-1*1i)-1)*y)

    cat("length(t)   ", length(t), "\n")
    t
}
integrate(inner.f.y, lower = 0.01, upper = 8)
```

This is the output on the console

```
> integrate(inner.f.y, lower = 0.01, upper = 8)
length(y)    21 
length(t)    21 
Error in integrate(inner.f.y, lower = 0.01, upper = 8) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong type
```

So what can it be this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `?integrate` (my emphasis):

> f : an R function taking a numeric first argument and returning a *numeric* vector of the same length.

Your function `inner.f.y` does not return a numeric vector, but a complex one:

```
a <- inner.f.y(1)

is.numeric(a)
[1] FALSE

is.complex(a)
[1] TRUE
```

As @Ben Bolker suggests, you could use `elliptic::myintegrate` instead:

```
elliptic::myintegrate(inner.f.y, lower = 0.01, upper = 8)
length(y)    21 
length(t)    21 
length(y)    21 
length(t)    21 
[1] -1.150277-1.380324i
```

Comment: `library(sos); findFn("integrate complex")` brings up (among others) http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/elliptic/html/myintegrate.html